# jquery link toggle with google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Im having problems working out how to get this toggle working, by default it hides the map and when you click show map i want the map to slide down and change the link test to hide map which then of course will slide back up but does not seem to be working..... anyone got any ideas?

Also if anyone knows of a solution for the google maps issue im also having please let me know, because the  made is hidden when you show / slides down it does not show most of the map (something about resizing i think i remember reading up on)

i have made a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/DfVBb/ although does not work there at all for some reason. thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<div class="slideToggleBox">
  <div id="map_div">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
<a href="#" id="slideToggle">show map</a>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#map_div').hide();
  $('#slideToggle').click(function() {
    $('#map_div').slideToggle('slow', function() {
      $('#slideToggle').text('hide map');
    }, function(){
      $('#slideToggle').text('show map');
    });
    return false
});
</script>
```

Maps JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.334583, -0.961674);
  var options = {  
    zoom: 15, // This number can be set to define the initial zoom level of the map
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };  
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), options);  
  var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/images/map-icon.png',
    new google.maps.Size(680, 178),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(18, 50)
  );
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(53.334583,-0.961674), 
  map: map,     
  icon: image
  });   
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your fiddle, it has to be cleaned.  Based on my understanding, you're trying to `toggle` Google maps on `button` click.

**Mistakes in your Fiddle:**

(1) The Google maps is not initialized.  The below is used to initialize Google maps.

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

(2) Your `.slideToggle()` has to be cleaned up.  It has be somehow like

```
$('#slideToggle').on('click', function () {
    $('#map_canvas').slideToggle('slow', function () {
        if ($('#slideToggle').text() !== "hide map") 
           $('#slideToggle').text('hide map');
        else 
           $('#slideToggle').text('show map');
    });
    return false;
});
```

I've created a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/2617/), please go through it and share your thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for your help works great however im still facing the issue with the map not fully loading, i have updated http://jsfiddle.net/yV6xv/2618/ with the correct width and height but as you will see it does not do the width set - i know this is a common issue with hiding and bring into place.

Comment: Oh.  Nice you got it.  I used to have `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')`

Comment: yeap, just got to work out why the custom marker is not working now lol

Comment: Thanks for your help, you got me in the line or fixing for sure !

Comment: Remember you should use `.on('click', function() {` instead of `.click(function() {`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work out a solution for this and also fixing the resize issue

```
$(function () {
  // create a center
  var c = new google.maps.LatLng(53.334583, -0.961674);

  //create map options object
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: c,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  $("#slideToggle").click(function () {
    $('#map_canvas').slideToggle(300, function(){
    if ($('#slideToggle').text() !== "hide map") $('#slideToggle').text('hide map');
    else $('#slideToggle').text('show map');
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize"); // resize map
    map.setCenter(c); // set the center
  }); // slide it down

});

});
```